# React-native spotify api call returning [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.items.name.map')]

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, api

Hey so I'm working on a react-native app that is using the spotify Api. I'm currently trying to call the endpoint which returns a users playlists. The way I want the app to work is that when the user presses a button it calls the api and gets that users playlists. This is what my code looks like:

```
export default function SpotifyGetPlaylist() {
   
    const { colors } = useTheme();
    const [token, setToken] = useState('');
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

   const getData = async() => {
           setToken (await AsyncStorage.getItem('@access_token'));
            console.log("token retrieved")
    }

   
    let playlistSearchApi = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists';
    const handleGetPlaylists = () => {
        fetch(playlistSearchApi, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }
          })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            let result = [];
            console.log(data)
            data.items.name.map(obj => result.push({title: [obj.name]}));
            setData(result);
        });
    }
    const renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return( 
            <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.playlistname}>{item.title[1]}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button onPress={handleGetPlaylists} color="#1DB954" style={{  width: 100 }} title="Get your playlists"/>
            <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.title[1]}
            />
            
        </View>
    )
}
```

The API call works fine for me and this is what the return data looks like

```
Object {
  "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/fsjgg/playlists?offset=0&limit=20",
  "items": Array [
    Object {
      "collaborative": false,
      "description": "",
      "external_urls": Object {
        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/5MwIvSj1Fc8N5BQByhsLvM",
      },
      "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/5MwIvSj1Fc8N5BQByhsLvM",
      "id": "5MwIvSj1Fc8N5BQByhsLvM",
      "images": Array [
        Object {
          "height": 640,
          "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2735a037fd63963c053475b00cf",
          "width": 640,
        },
      ],
      "name": "Run",
```

I'm getting [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.item.name')] so I'm guessing the problem is in my render item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `handleGetPlaylists` in the line:

```
data.items.name.map(obj => result.push({title: [obj.name]}));
```

According to the API response, you probably want this:

```
data.items.map(obj => result.push({title: [obj.name]}));
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response this cleared out the issue, but I'm still unable to render the actual playlist names. Any idea why this would be happening? Theres no errors in the console either

Comment: I got it to work the problem was in my own renderitem return const item = ({item}) => {
        return( 
            <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={{color:'white'}}>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

Comment: before the fix it was set to {item.title[1]} which I changed to {item.title}